# Parameterization of a Idempotent Filter

Tags: fft, filters, frequency-spectrum, convolution

I'm interested in if there has been research into how to parameterize filters so they are idempotent. I'm looking for the property shown below:

$$
h \circledast h = h
$$

I searched around and found ["Convolution Idempotents with a given Zero-set"](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.00739), but this seems to be a special case for the problem and not a general parameterization I could use.

Comment: Are you interested in circular convolution? Discrete or continuous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The frequency response of the corresponding filters must satisfy

$H^2(\omega)=H(\omega)\tag{1}$

This was already pointed out in [Hilmar's answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/79331/4298), but the conclusion is not that the only option is $H(\omega)=1$ for all $\omega$.

The correct conclusion from $(1)$ is that the frequency response $H(\omega)$ must equal either $0$ or $1$ for any frequency. One obvious example is an ideal (unity gain) low pass filter, the frequency response of which equals $1$ in the passband, and zero in the stopband. All other ideal frequency-selective filters also satisfy $(1)$ (highpass, bandpass, etc.).

So there are clearly infinitely many ideal filters satisfying $(1)$. Just choose a filter with an arbitrary number of passbands with gain $1$ (and arbitrary edge frequencies), and ideal stopbands with gain $0$.

Note that apart from the trivial filters $H(\omega)=0$ and $H(\omega)=1$, none of the filters satisfying $(1)$ can be realized exactly.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this was really helpful. I was wondering, is there a wider class of filters if: h = h * conj(h)?

Comment: @Torkoal: That would result in a similar argument, but what is the relevance of $h*h^*$?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that there is much there to be looked at.

If

$$h(t) = h(t) \circledast h(t) $$

then
$$H(\omega) = H(\omega) \cdot H(\omega) $$

which has two solutions

$$H(\omega) = 1, H(\omega) = 0$$

So any transfer function that consists ONLY of 0 and 1 will be idempotent. However mixing zeros and ones will create discontinuities and make the impulse response infinitely long and non-causal, so you can't actualy implement the filter.

The only practical implementation that I can see is $H(\omega) = 1$ or

$$h(t) = \delta(t) $$

So it looks like the only idempotent impulse response is the delta dirac.

Comment: There are infinitely many (ideal) filters satisfying that property. Think of an ideal low-pass filter, etc.

Comment: Fair point. My bad: $x^2-x = 0$ has obviously two solutions :-) . Still, I think the delta dirac is the only implementable filter that fits the bill. Ideal lowpass filters (and equivalent) exist on paper but not in the real world.